# Invalid Gradle JDK configuration found

Tags: android, gradle, java-home

I have this mistake for gradle im Android Studio.

> Error:Invalid Gradle JDK configuration found. Open Gradle Settings
>   Platform SDK does not point to valid JDK (C:/Program
>   Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_31)

This is my JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45

Why it is looking for older version of java?

Comment: Are you running in Android Studio, Eclipse or command line?

Comment: Have you checked your settings in the project structure in Android Studio?

Answer (score 2):

Follow these direction:

In Android Studio: select File > Project Structure > JDK location. Specify the JDK to the folder of your currently installed JDK. And specify the SDK location as well.

Make sure your JDK/SDK are up to date..

Answer (score -1):

Try to use Java 6 or 7, That will fix it.